# Program not working (no any error/warning)

Tags: java, android

I'm confused that why program not responding. I waited for 2-3 mins at system says:

> Program not responding. Do you want to close?

So, my this is my codes.

**Main activity**

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> client_name_arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> client_name_arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> client_name_map = new LinkedHashMap<>();


// onCreate() method
client_name_arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Satish.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
client_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.client_name);

// set fields only readable
client_name.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
client_name.setKeyListener(null);
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.client_name:
                        try {
                            /** clear <code>client_name_map</code> to prevent reassigning the elements  */
                            client_name_map.clear();
                            client_name_map = kliyentDAO.getClients();

                            /** clear <code>client_name_arrayList</code> to prevent reassigning the elements  */
                            client_name_arrayList.clear();
                            client_name_arrayList.addAll(client_name_map.keySet());

                            /** clear <code>client_name_arrayAdapter</code> to prevent reassigning the elements  */
                            client_name_arrayAdapter.clear();
                            client_name_arrayAdapter.addAll(client_name_arrayList);

                            AlertDialog.Builder builder_client_name = new AlertDialog.Builder(Satish.this);
                            builder_client_name.setTitle("Malı seçin");
                            if (client_name_arrayAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                                builder_client_name.setMessage("Heç bir müştəri tapılmadı.");
                                builder_client_name.setNegativeButton("İmtina", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                builder_client_name.setSingleChoiceItems(client_name_arrayAdapter, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        _which[0] = which;
                                        id = client_name_map.get(client_name_arrayList.get(which));
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("İmtina", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }).setPositiveButton("Seç", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        client_name.setText(client_name_arrayList.get(_which[0]));
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            builder_client_name.create().show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.wtf("Unknown bug: ", e.toString());
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
}
```

**DAO class**

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> getClients() {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT idkliy, kliyentad FROM " + TABLE_KLIYENT, null);
    cursor.moveToPosition(0);
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        linkedHashMap.put(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_KLIYENTAD)), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IDKLIY)));
    }
    cursor.close();

    return linkedHashMap;
}
```

I want to show an alert box, when user clicks the `client_name` field, and this 
alert box should be *filled* with `client_name_arrayAdapter`. Shortly, I can describe the structure of code above:

> **functionality of DAO class**
>
> Programs gets some fields value from **local** database. The `linkedHashMap` filled with this data. And the function returns the filled (if no data in database empty)
>   linkedHashMap.
>
> **functionality of MainActivity**
>
> **local** linkedHashMap (named as `map` in code above) equals to what the *DAO class function* returns. `client_name_arrayList` filled with this `map`, and the `client_name_arrayAdapter` filled with *client_name_arrayList*. And at the end, array adapter'll set as `adapter` to `alertBuilder`.

I don't think that this is better or worse way, but other parts of application are working correctly (without any problem).

## Edit

There's no any *problematic log* in logcat (level **`VERBOSE`**). When I clicked the field, the logs:

```
08-11 22:01:20.625  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1940K, 32% free 6516K/9572K, paused 22ms, total 23ms
08-11 22:01:21.075  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2060K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:21.475  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:21.876  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:22.326  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
08-11 22:01:22.787  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:23.217  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:23.607  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:24.028  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-11 22:01:24.438  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-11 22:01:24.859  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-11 22:01:25.329  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:25.790  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:26.210  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:26.610  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-11 22:01:27.041  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
08-11 22:01:27.441  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:27.852  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
08-11 22:01:28.262  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:28.662  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:29.073  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:29.553  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:30.034  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:30.464  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
08-11 22:01:30.875  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:31.335  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:31.795  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:32.276  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-11 22:01:32.746  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
08-11 22:01:33.207  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
08-11 22:01:33.677  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:34.138  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:34.538  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:34.938  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:35.339  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:35.729  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-11 22:01:36.140  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:36.540  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:37.001  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:37.461  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:37.921  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-11 22:01:38.382  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:38.812  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-11 22:01:39.253  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-11 22:01:39.773  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
08-11 22:01:40.214  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2048K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-11 22:01:40.644  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
08-11 22:01:41.135  20922-20922/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2047K, 33% free 6491K/9680K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
```

Any helpful comment/answer appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Might be a good idea to move the cursor ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not advancing the cursor in this loop!  Add `moveToNext()` like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT idkliy, kliyentad FROM " + TABLE_KLIYENT, null);
cursor.moveToPosition(0);
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    linkedHashMap.put(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_KLIYENTAD)), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IDKLIY)));
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: Add `cursor.moveToNext();` after the `linkedHashMap.put` line... I'll update the code with the solution

Comment: Oh my God... How I missed this line here. Thanks. I'll accept as answer after few mins.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT idkliy, kliyentad FROM " + TABLE_KLIYENT, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        linkedHashMap.put(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_KLIYENTAD)), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_IDKLIY)));
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
return  linkedHashMap;
```

---

**Please note:**

Most likely you are getting an error.

You need to adjust your log cat to show them in your console.

Perhaps you have a filter that is not displaying the error.

Comment: @Meda, regarding your initial "answer," please post comments on the question, not in an answer. Your response is now the oldest on the question, even though the actual answer came last.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue as it would appear to me.

You have this loop:

```
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    linkedHashMap.put(...);
}
```

But you never actually change the position of the cursor, so it will never exit the condition of the while loop, resulting in a hung thread.

Because you are doing this on the UI thread, the app fails to respond to Android, and therefore appears as if it has crashed.

Try adding `cursor.moveToNext()` after you put an object.